# Selected select on default ember js

Tags: ember.js

I have a model `Currencies`. Fields in the model are `name:string` and `default:boolean`.
On the backend only one of records in database can have `default:true.` I want it to be selected by default in select in Ember js.

**Please give me an example how to make such select and use it**

Example:

```
name: type1  default: false
name: type2  default: true
name: type3  default: false
```

I want to generate such select :

```
<selected>
  <option>type1</option
  <option selected=selected>type2</option
  <option>type3</option
</selected>
```

Route.js

```
@route 'addincome', { path: 'operations/addincome' }
EmberMoney.AddincomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    EmberMoney.IncomeOperation.createRecord()
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('currencies', EmberMoney.Currency.find())
    controller.set('content', model)
```

addincome.handlebars

// Some output with Incomes records

```
{{view EmberMoney.Select viewName="select"
                    contentBinding="controller.currencies"
                    optionLabelPath="content.name"
                    optionValuePath="content.id"
                    selectionBinding="controller.defaultType"}}
```

addincome_controller.js

```
EmberMoney.AddincomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  setDefaultCurrency: function(){
    if(this.get('currencies.isLoaded')){
      this.set('defaultType', this.get('currencies').findProperty('default'));
    }
  }.observes('currencies.isLoaded')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectionBinding` for the selection, and `ComputedProperty` to find the appropriate item

### Update

```
EmberMoney.AddincomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  setDefaultCurrency: function(){
    if(this.get('currencies.isLoaded')){
      this.set('defaultType', this.get('currencies').findProperty('default'));
    }
  }.observes('currencies.isLoaded')
})
```

The advantage of using `isLoaded` over `@each` for the observer is that the observer wont get fired everytime a currency is added instead it makes sure to set the value once the entire collection is loaded, Again it is upto the use case to determine which to use when

Details about [findProperty](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_findProperty)

Hope this helps

**Screenshot**
[image: List of the currencies]

Comment: i changed my code a little bit and use your answer. It doesn't work for me cause **return this.get('currencies').findProperty('default')** gives me **undefined**. Also i put ObjectController because when the code was ArrayController i have **error while loading route**.  Can you look my code once more time? Thanks

Comment: I have  error **Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){
    if(this.get('currencies.isLoaded')){
      this.set('defaultType', this.get('currencies').findProperty('default'));
    }
  } has no method 'observer'**

Comment: Sorry typing mistake it is "observes" instead of "observer"

Comment: i have no errors not but it doesn't work. when i alert **this.get('currencies').findProperty('default')** it gives me undefined. What cat be the problem?

Comment: try console.log(this.get('currencies.length')) and see if there are records, also make sure there is the 'default' property if there are records by doing console.log(this.get('currencies.firstObject.default'))

Comment: **console.log(this.get('currencies.length'))** gives me 0. Mb you can look my app? [link](https://github.com/EJIqpEP/ember-money/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/controllers/addincome_controller.js)

Comment: May be your database doesnt have records, do a rake db:seed on the terminal, check the image in the answer ! I can see the currencies on the page

Comment: Thanks that you look on my app. On page /operations/addincome i have select with my currencies but selected function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My answer builds upon that one already posted. The answer is to use the `selectionBinding` and a clever way to set it up:

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="controller.types"
   optionLabelPath="content.name"
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   selectionBinding="controller.selectedCurrency"
}}

EmberMoney.IncomesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selectedCurrency : null,
  currenciesObserver: function(){
    var currencies = this.get("currencies");
    var default = currencies.findProperty("default");
    if(default)
      this.set("selectedCurrency", default);
  }.observes('currencies.@each')
});
```

**How does the solution work?**

- We set up a selectionBinding (two way) between the Select control and your controller. If you set a currency in your controller in the property 'selectedCurrency', it will be the selected value in the Select control. Vice versa if you select a currency in the Select Box, it will be set in your controller.
- I am doing the initial setup with the helper of an observer. **The observer is called each time the watched currencies array changes.**
- Every time it is called, it tries to find a default currency. If it finds one, it sets it in your selectedCurrency property. Now the selectionBinding kicks and does its magic for you.
- An additional advantage of this solution is, that you can grab the selected value easily from the property, if the user chooses another currency.